# Design Report using ReportViewer Wizard in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reportviewer

I want to create the report in my application using the reportViewer control.

I have added the ReportViewer control to WindowsForm from the toolbox. From the smart tag I, I selected the option Design a New Report. When I click on the design a new report, I am getting a .rdlc report, but I want to design it using a Wizard. I am not getting the Wizard can anyone tell me how to get the wizard so that I can design the report in simple manner.

Please help me out in getting the wizard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no wizard for creating reports under Visual Studio 2005.
Sorry - your just going to have to cope with the WYSIWYG editor provided.